# How to create a sublist that I can edit and update back to the original list

Tags: c#, list, reference, parameter-passing

I am writing code for a program that players poker. My question is concerning reference and value passing in Lists.

My program has a Player object, a Dealer object, and a PokerTable object. The PokerTable has two Lists of players, one called players and one called winners. The list of players is passed to the Dealer object's DetermineWinner method which passes back a list with the winner (or winners in the case of a tie). The PokerTable then uses the list of winners to determine who to pay money to.

```
    class PokerTable
    {
        private Dealer dealer;
        private List<Player> players;
        private List<Player> winners;            

        private void EndHand()
        {
            winners = dealer.DetermineWinner(players);
            PayPlayers();
            winners.Clear();
            PrepareForNextHand();
        }

        private void PayPlayers()
        {
           /* code here uses the winners list to determine
            * how much to pay each winner and adds that money
            * to the player object */
        }
```

My question is whether adding money to the player objects in the winners list will also effect the original player objects in the original players list.

Comment: You should be able to easily just do it and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tested this yourself in the debugger? Generally, the contents of a list are references to the instances of each list item.

Comment: I tried it myself and got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<Player>` is a list of references to `Player` objects.

If a reference in two separate lists points to the same `Player` then updating a `Player` in one list will appear to have changed that `Player` in the other list as well.

```
class Player
{
     internal int Money;
}

// ...

    Player player = new Player{ Money = 700 };
    List<Player> list1 = new List<Player>{player};
    List<Player> list2 = new List<Player>{player};

    list1[0].Money = 400;

    Assert.AreEqual(400, list2[0].Money); // Assertion passes.
```

On the other hand, if your list points to a value type then of course the changes are not reflected:

```
var money = 700;
var list1 = new List<int>{money};
var list2 = new List<int>{money};

list1[0] = 400;

Assert.AreNotEqual(400, list2[0]); // Assertion passes.
```

Comment: correct, provided that Player is indeed a class and not a struct

Comment: Player is a class and not a struct. Thanks for your help, the code works fine